# Django: many to many circular reference

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-models

I have a problem in my models because I have a circular reference in a many to many relationship

This is a part of my web app, the Sessions are of a group (a group can have more than one session) and each Session have more than one assistant but the assistants only can be members of the session's group

Here are my models:

```
class GroupMember(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Volunteer, null=True, blank=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.member)

class Session(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    assistants = models.ManyToManyField(GroupMember,through=SessionAssistant)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

class SessionAssistant(models.Model):
    assistant = models.ForeignKey(GroupMember)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assist = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ability = models.IntegerField(null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              validators=[MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(1)])
    performance = models.IntegerField(null=True,
                                  blank=True,
                                  validators=[MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(1)])
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.assistant)
```

Comment: Can we get a traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you change `assistants = models.ManyToManyField(GroupMember,through=SessionAssistant)` to `assistants = models.ManyToManyField(GroupMember,through='SessionAssistant')`?

Comment: Thanks, I don't see that i have it without ' ' , now works